# Qt - Q_OBJECT and macros

Tags: qt, macros, qobject

In `Qt`, we know that `Q_OBJECT` is a **macro**. What does *macro* mean in this context? Especially that I have found that the term *macro* may have several different definitions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

*Macro* simply means that `Q_OBJECT` is in fact a C++ macro. It is defined in `src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h` and the definition reads

```
#define Q_OBJECT \
public: \
    Q_OBJECT_CHECK \
    static const QMetaObject staticMetaObject; \
    Q_OBJECT_GETSTATICMETAOBJECT \
    virtual const QMetaObject *metaObject() const; \
    virtual void *qt_metacast(const char *); \
    QT_TR_FUNCTIONS \
    virtual int qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void **); \
private:
```

`Q_OBJECT_CHECK` is another macro that is used for checking, if the `Q_OBJECT` macro has been used in a class. The other expressions define the meta-object and utility methods for the signal/slot mechanism as well as for translations.